# Might I have 2 vents for my gas dryer?

Tags: gas, exhaust

I have a gas (propane) dryer. We just had a huge amount of snow 5ft. plus drifts around my house. This morning I turned on the dryer and started to smell propane. I went out and cleaned out the lint vent outside. In the past it had been clogged with lint but I never smelled any propane in those cases the clothes just weren't drying. Could there be another outside vent for the dryer exhaust other than the lint vent on the outside of the house that I'm not aware of? My furnace and water heater vent on the back of the house the dryer lint vent is on the front of the house. I'm afraid there is another exhaust vent for the dryer somewhere around my house buried in snow but with so much snow I don't know where to look. 
Thanks
Worried in PA

Comment: There should be a vent going up through the roof to vent the combustion gasses , I have not seen a dryer with 2 separate vents for the air discharge, if smelling Propane you may have a dirty burner and are not getting a complete burn, I would check the burners some times they get blocked with dust , lint or have a service tech give them a good cleaning

Comment: Is the dryer is old enough that it has a pilot light? The lint may have blocked the vent door open.  A large gust of wind may have blown out the pilot light.

Comment: Thank you. The dryer is getting warm and the clothes were drying so I'm guessing if there is a pilot light it is still on. The dryer is 8 years old. My husband cleaned out the lint from inside the dryer a month or so ago it was pretty caked in there. I'm not sure if he cleaned the burners or not. Of course now he's out of town. :{ Thanks again for all your advise.

Comment: @EdBeal -- the combustion gases on a gas dryer go out the same vent as the lint.  This does smell of incomplete combustion, though...

Comment: Thanks to all. Once I cleaned out the lint the smell of propane went away. I was concerned because I had never had that happen before.